# LINQ: how to add multiple variables to LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, switch-statement

I have a a controller action called List that take the following parameters

int Filer, int Field, int Operator, string QueryValue

```
public enum Filter
{
    ActiveEmployee,
    OnHoldEmployee,
    InactiveEmployee
}
public enum Field
{
    Name,
    ABRAID,
    JobTitle,
    LocationCode,
    Department
}
public enum Operator
{
    Contains,
    StartWith,
    EndWith,
    EqualTo
}
```

Possible cases:

```
Select employee where Name Equals "Value"

Select employee where Name EndWith with "Value"

Select employee where Name StartWith with "Value"

Select employee where JobTitle Contains "Value"

Select employee where Department Equals "Value"
```

I'm using LINQ to query the database

```
Employees = from p in DB.Employees
            where p.AWCID.Contains(queryvalue)
            select p;
```

But thats mean I have to wite nested switch case to cover all cases.
It's over 180 lines of code to cover 3 variables,

I'm not very aware with LINQ syntax to support multiple values.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?  Or LINQ to objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the query will be only one type of query (contains, startswith, etc.), I would try something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(queryType, value)
{
    var Employees = from p in DB.Employees
            select p;

    // could use a switch statement here as well
    if (queryType == "contains")
        return Employees.where(e => e.contains(value));
    else if...
}
```

You could also make the query types an enum.

Comment: I tried the following but not working, trying to dynamically get the Class Property name based on Field 

Employee.All().Where(p => p."PropertyName" == QueryValue)
Qouted PropertyName would be replaced with:

     string PropertyName = ((Field)Field).ToString(); 
 List<Employee> Employees2 = Employee.Find(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(T).Name == QueryValue).ToList();

I'm getting error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does complicate the query.  If using Entity Framework, you could consider Entity SQL which would be a lot less complex as you can dynamically build the entire query as a string.  Or, LINQ to SQL has Dynamic LINQ which also supports textual based queries...